# Ubuntu freezes randomly - Windows works

Tags: 19.10, intel, freeze, crash, idle

I have this old computer that I've been trying to run Ubuntu on, but it keeps freezing.
Windows works perfect, no problem having days of uptime under hard load.
It's not specific to 19.10, been trying with earlier versions of Ubuntu with same results.

The freezes seem to be random. Sometimes I can play Rocket League for an hour without any problems, a few minutes later the machine will freeze idling at desktop or 2 minutes after a reboot. The only thing I'm certain of, is that I can't find a way to trigger it more often.

When it freezes, it's a hard freeze. SSH sessions to the computer dies.
Keyboard is unresponsive, can't go to another console or turn on/off caps lock light.

No faults in memtest. No high temperatures. Upgraded to latest motherboard bios, no change.
Been tailing dmesg, kernel and syslogs without seeing anything special.

```
Hardware:
Intel i5 760
Gigabyte P55-USB3
Geforce GTX 670 2GB (Running 435 driver)
4x 4GB DDR3 1600
2x Samsung 830
IDE DVD/RW
Corsair HX750
```

I don't know how to further analyze the issue, since I never see any errors/warnings and I can't find a way to trigger the issue.

### Is there some way I can see more details?

Adding information as requested by @K7AAY

I haven't enabled hibernation, unless it's enabled by default.

```
free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          16004        1130       13883           3         990       14582
Swap:          2047           0        2047
```

Comment: Please run _free -m_ then highlight and copy the result, then come back here, click [edit], and paste the text into your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Also, have you enabled hibernation for your system? Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue.

This system had a slight overclock, that I had forgot about. Nothing was wrong with the overclock itself, the settings in bios are 100% stable.

But! A modern Linux kernel overrides bios/uefi settings for Intel C-states via the Intel_idle driver. So, the C-state settings that was supposed to be set from bios, actually got overridden in Linux.

This is what caused the random freezing, since the system was perfectly stable as long as the C-state didn't change. That meant it worked perfectly under heavy load, but as soon as the system started to switch between idle and light load, the C-states fluctuated a lot and hung the system.

My solution was to lock the C-state in grub via a kernel parameter. GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet intel_idle.max_cstate=1"

Comment: thanks! it works for me as well